# Chrome extension, options page, a black rectangle is displayed instead of a list

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Quite recently, instead of a simple `<select>` list, I started to get a black rectangle.

[image]

Does anyone know what's wrong with it and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: It's a bug, https://crbug.com/1015298, should be fixed in current Chrome versions.